# Function/Procedure to add values in non-1NF format separated by delimiter

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, recursive-query

I need a function written in MySQL to add numbers together (positive and negative) that are in a single column and separated by a delimiter.  The delimiter in this case is "?".  The function also needs to ignore extraneous characters that are not numeric, not a minus sign ("-"), not a period ("."), and not a delimiter (e.g., "?").

An example is a column named "BalAdjAmt" whose values could be:

```
500.00?500.00?-1000.00
500.00
500.00?500.00
500.00?500.00?-1000.00 B
```

The result of the function when run on this dataset should be:

```
0
500.00
1000.00
0
```

Any pointers would be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Any pointers would be helpful*"—normalise your data.  Relational Database Management Systems are, strangely enough, designed to work with *relational* data; anything else just makes your life difficult.  If you're unable to alter the schema so that it becomes relational, then it's strongly indicative that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Normalise your data. This is a classic example of someone thinking that TNF is not suitable for their application or problem domain. Now you have crap data that you can not process.

Comment: I am working with a client that has an off-the-shelf system (DebtCon) that stores the data this way, so there is really no option to normalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [common_schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html) to facilitate the work. Then you can create a function like this:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fn_test`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `fn_test`(`_value` VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS DECIMAL(7,2)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_iteration`, `_num_tokens` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `delim` CHAR(1) DEFAULT '?';
    DECLARE `_return` DECIMAL(7,2) DEFAULT 0;

    SET `_num_tokens` := (SELECT `common_schema`.`get_num_tokens`(`_value`, `delim`));

    WHILE `_iteration` < `_num_tokens` DO
        SET `_iteration` := `_iteration` + 1;
        SET `_return` := `_return` + (SELECT CAST(`common_schema`.`split_token`(`_value`, `delim`, _iteration) AS DECIMAL(7,2)));
    END WHILE;    

    RETURN `_return`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```